# Findall python отправить больше 1 match[0]

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

как сделать чтобы если `findall` нашёл больше **1** match (тоесть `match[0]`, `match[1]`) то чтобы

```
message = await client.send_message(group, match[0])
```

и

```
message = await client.send_message(group, match[1])
```

а если только 1 то только

```
message = await client.send_message(group, match[0])
```

Например дают текст :

```
DDDD DDDD DDDD DDDD
```

мой скрипт :

```
match = re.findall(r'\bDDDD\b', event.message.message) 
message = await client.send_message(group, match[0])
```

и если текст

```
DDDD DDDD DDDD DDDD
```

он отправит только 1 DDDD

а если сделать

```
message = await client.send_message(group, match[1])
```

а дадут текст 1 DDDD то даст ошибку
а мне надо чтобы отправляло все 4 штуки DDDD

Comment: Например дают текст :
DDDD
DDDD
DDDD
DDDD
мой скрипт :  match = re.findall(r'\bDDDD\b', event.message.message)
message = await client.send_message(group, match[0])
и если 4 штуки DDDD он отправит только 1 DDDD
а если сделать message = await client.send_message(group, match[1])
а дадут текст 1 DDDD то даст ошибку

Comment: Изменил @StanislavVolodarskiy

Comment: Сделайте цикл по массиву `match`.

Comment: подробнее можно?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy можно подробнее как это сделать? я просто новичок в питоне

Comment: `for m in match: ...`.

Comment: а зачем вы, "новичок в питоне", беретесь за такие проекты без знания базовых основ языка и программирования вообще?

Comment: для себя делаю.

Comment: `for m in match: message = await client.send_message(group, m)` и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте цикл `for`:

```py
for m in match:
    message = await client.send_message(group, m)
```

`findall` возвращает список строк, так что этого достаточно.